# Filling empty columns with mode value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to fill nan for gender column with the mode using pandas but my way does not work

```
# change gender to string datatype
df['gender'] = df['gender'].map(str)

# Replace empty gender(73) with there most common gender
mode = df['gender'].mode()
df['gender'].fillna(mode, inplace=True)

df['gender'].value_counts()
```

**Output**

> M      4417

> F      1504

> nan      73

> Name: gender, dtype: int64

Comment: code wise you already to be doing the correct think

Comment: Is possible share real data in column by pickle? Because not idea what is wrong.

Comment: You can try `df[['gender']].to_pickle('gender.pkl')` and share by gdocs, or wetransfer or dropbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test with data:

```
df = pd.read_pickle('gender.pkl')
print (df)
       gender
0           M
1           M
2           M
3           M
4           M
      ...
114746      M
114747      M
114748      M
114749      M
114750      F
```

---

```
print (df['gender'].isna().sum())
785

print (df['gender'].value_counts())
M    85893
F    28073
Name: gender, dtype: int64
```

You need select first value of `mode` by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
mode = df['gender'].mode().iat[0]
df['gender'].fillna(mode, inplace=True)


print (df['gender'].isna().sum())
0

print (df['gender'].value_counts())

M    86678
F    28073
Name: gender, dtype: int64
```

Comment: removing ```df['gender'] = df['gender'].map(str)``` did not solve the issue. It masked it. when i did ```df["gender"].isnull().sum()``` after ```df['gender'] = df['gender'].fillna(mode)``` i got 73

Comment: @ShadowWalker - One idea - How working `df['gender'] = df['gender'].replace(['nan', 'NaN'], np.nan)` instead `df['gender'] = df['gender'].map(str)` ?

Comment: No changes, still has null values

Comment: @ShadowWalker - answer was edited. Need `.iat[0]`